# Is there any way to disable static content generation in Magento2

Tags: magento2, admin

I am working on magento2. I am curious about, **Is there any way to disable pub/static content generation** ? Meanwhile I was also thinking that why there is no option to reindex from admin ?

Comment: You can do reindex from admin by system menu.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `developer` mode and then removing the existing static files? A similar question can be found [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105551/magento-2-how-to-make-magento-not-to-cache-static-content-of-checkout-module).

Comment: I had already enabled developer mode but still it is caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pub/static should remain empty if you set to developer mode.

If you have ran the static asset deployment script via the CLI it will get populated regardless of the development mode you have set.

You may have issues if you have deleted your static assets and also deleted the .htaccess file along with it.

Comment: this is patently false. using developer mode results in pub/static being automatically generated on page load every time that you delete it. If you set production mode, nothing will be generated in pub/static unless you manually go and deploy static files.